# .STL 3D objects using Three.js not working in IE

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

I have created a rotating 3D model using [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) (using r56) and [STLLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js) loading `.stl(ascii)` file
Its working fine in FF and chrome but not in IE(9), its showing blank screen
 and gives the following error

```
SCRIPT5009: 'DataView' is undefined 
STLLoader.js, line 82 character 3
```

well I am aware of the fact that `webglRenderer` doesn't work in IE but `CanvasRenderer` does,
but as I said that I m loading `.stl` file

I also tried using CanvasRenderer in case of `IE`
Is it correct? I mean does the combination of `CanvasRenderer` and `stlLoading` works? as its not working in my case

So is there any way or any plugin, or any other alternative to make my work IE9 compatible?
Just need assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately IE does not natively support WebGL and probably never will. They claim that it's a security risk http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2011/06/16/webgl-considered-harmful.aspx and historically have neglected OpenGL support in favor of their competing standard Direct3D.

Yes, you can use a plugin to enable WebGL in IE. Either IEWebGL http://iewebgl.com/ or Chrome Frame http://www.google.com/chromeframe.

Answer (score 0):

Did You updated your IE 9 , 'cause three days ago , there was cumulative update for IE 9. IE 9 brings some unwanted security measures which make things sometimes hard , or even impossible. Check IE 9 security settings , it may blocking it. Sometimes , it is compatibility issue , sometimes , it is browser related thing.